# @font-face css for Futura Bk BT Bok.ttf not working

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

How can I add 'Futura Bk BT Bok.ttf' font to my website by css @font-face rule
my css begins like..

```
    @font-face
{

font-family: abcd;

src:url(Futura Bk BT Bok.ttf) format('truetype');

} 

body{


margin:0;


padding:0;


font-family:abcd;


font-size:100%;

}
```

but this is not working.. :(

Answer (score 1):

your scr: url() path does not look right.

It should be a path to your font file - there should be no spaces in your file name.

try renaming your ttf file and correct the path in src declaration.

Also, note that ttf is not supported by all browsers, so make sure you test it in the ones that do support this format (check browser support here: http://caniuse.com/ttf)